# Bulma CSS ScrollDown Navbar

Tags: css, framework

No site oficial do [Bulma CSS](https://bulma.io/) percebe-se que ao dar um scroll down na pagina o menu navbar aparece no topo.
A propriedade  transform: translateY inspecionada no navegador aparece sendo usada para projetar esse efeito.
Como não há uso do Jquery, como fazer para copiar esse mesmo efeito usando apenas o javascript/css?

Comment: Ao contrario, quando rola pra baixo, o menu desaparece, depois rola pra cima e ele aparece. Não seria isso?

Comment: Não ...quando a página rola pra baixo o menu fixa no topo. Quando rola pra cima o menu some. Mas indempente disso. COmo essa acão está acontecendo? nao achei o js ou css que está executando essa operacao

Comment: Comigo como como com o Dvd, rolei pra baixo sumiu, mas uma pequena rolagem pra cima o menu apareceu, independente da posição da página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independentemente de como o site citado faz, esse efeito é facilmente conseguido utilizando `transition` e `position: fixed` na `div` do menu.

Para esconder o menu, você muda o `top` para o valor da altura do menu em negativo, e para mostrar, `top: 0`.

No exemplo abaixo, essa alternância se dá quando o valor do `scroll` for maior ou menor que 20 pixels.

Você pode ajustar o tempo da animação em `transition: top 0.3s;`, onde `0.3s` significa 300 milissegundos.

```js
var srcl_dir = 20;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
   var scrl = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
   if(scrl >= srcl_dir){
      document.querySelector("#menu").style.top = "-50px";
   }else{
      document.querySelector("#menu").style.top = "0";
   }
   
   srcl_dir = scrl <= 20 ? 20 : scrl;
});
```

```css
html, body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#menu{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background: yellow;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   transition: top 0.3s;
}

#conteudo{
   display: block;
   height: 1200px;
   padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
   menu
</div>
<div id="conteudo">
   conteúdo
</div>
```